# Moshi Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am developing an Android application.
I get the following error when receiving information from the server:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $.data
```

I will attach the following files to the attachment for more details.

Server Response:

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "reserve_type": "history",
            "reserve_id": 163,
            "payment_status": true,
            "ship": {
                "code": "#1",
                "photo": "#",
                "name": "",
                "rate": null
            },
            "factor_detail": {
                "trip": "526.00",
                "transit": "356.40",
                "extra_hour": {
                    "price": "1052.00",
                    "time": "2:0"
                },
                "items": [],
                "reserve_dates": {
                    "start_date": "27 of July 01:30 PM",
                    "end_date": "27 of July 04:30 PM"
                },
                "product": {
                    "code": "#1",
                    "name": "",
                    "photo": "#"
                },
                "discount": "0.00",
                "tax": "348.19",
                "finalReservePriceWithoutPercent": "2282.59",
                "finall_reserve_price": "2282.59"
            },
            "comment": null,
            "scores": {
                "items": [],
                "final_rate": null
            }
        },
        {
            "reserve_type": "on_going",
            "reserve_id": 168,
            "payment_status": false,
            "ship": {
                "code": "#28",
                "photo": "#",
                "name": "",
                "rate": null
            },
            "factor_detail": {
                "trip": "3297.50",
                "transit": "1087.50",
                "extra_hour": {
                    "price": "17147.00",
                    "time": "13:0"
                },
                "items": [],
                "reserve_dates": {
                    "start_date": "29 of July 07:30 AM",
                    "end_date": "29 of July 11:00 PM"
                },
                "product": {
                    "code": "#28",
                    "name": "",
                    "photo": "#"
                },
                "discount": "0.00",
                "tax": "3875.76",
                "finalReservePriceWithoutPercent": "25407.76",
                "finall_reserve_price": "25407.76"
            },
            "cancel": false,
            "nearest": true
        }
    ],
    "code": 200
}
```

ResponseBody.kt:

```
class ResponseBody<T>(
    val status: String,
    val data: T,
    val code: Int
)
```

ResReserve.kt:

```
data class ResReserves(
    val reserves: List<ApiReserve>
)
```

ApiReserve.kt:

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@Parcelize
data class ApiReserve(
    @Json(name = "reserve_type")
    val reserveType: String,
    @Json(name = "reserve_id")
    val reserveId: Int,
    @Json(name = "payment_status")
    val paymentStatus: Boolean,
    @Json(name = "ship")
    val ship: ApiShip,
    @Json(name = "factor_detail")
    val factorDetail: ApiFactorDetail,
    @Json(name = "comment")
    val comments: @RawValue Any? = null,
    @Json(name = "scores")
    val scores: ApiScores?,
    @Json(name = "scores")
    val cancel: Boolean?,
    @Json(name = "nearest")
    val nearest: Boolean?
) : Parcelable
```

MyApiInterface:

```
interface ReservesApi {
    @GET("#")
    suspend fun getReserves(
        @Query("page[number]") pageNumber: Int? = null,
        @Query("page[limit]") pageLimit: Int? = null
    ): ResponseBody<ResReserves>
}
```

Please guide me so that I can fix this problem
Thank you for your attention dear friends

Comment: Can you please post ApiFactorDetail, ApiScores, ApiShip models' structures as well?

Comment: @Rinat I found the problem, thank you for your attention

Comment: How did you solve it ? Mind sharing what you did for others (myself included ) please?

Comment: @xbass It depends on your response.
I used the list instead of an object and my problem was solved.

Comment: Found out what my issue was, and it's the same thing, got it solved. My understanding is you gotta structure your data/response models based on that json response you get.